# How to use correlation ID for debugging

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

How can I use correlation ID in powershell to debug an issue in azure, Can anybody have any syntax that I Can use here.

Comment: If my understanding is right, maybe you want to use `Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId "*****"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, maybe you could use [`Get-AzureRmLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/get-azurermlog?view=azurermps-4.2.0) to get a log of events. Example: Get an event log by correlation ID

```
Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId "60c694d0-e46f-4c12-bed1-9b7aef541c23"
```

But, I suggest you could let us know what resource you want to debug, it better helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: I want to check some log Events that are happening, let mE try this and then I'll reply to you.